# Uncaught Type error in Google console

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

While creating a basic google map I AM getting the following error: Uncaught typeError: Cannot read property 'maps' of undefined

Index.html file is:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBKNPX_2z_JDWcyADlzzFk9JChR4TwhZLQ"
    async defer></script>
    </script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>




</html>
```

the script .js file is:

```
    (function(window,google)
{
//maps options
var options={
    center: {
    lat:"0",
    lng:"0"
},
zoom:0
},
//maps
element=document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
map = new google.maps.Map(element,options);
}(window,window.google));
```

The css file is:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    height:100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#map-canvas {
    height: 100%; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you the Google Maps Javascript API v3 is not loaded when you are trying to run code that depends on it.

You are loading the Google Maps Javascript API v3 using "async defer", but loading your script inline, you need to either defer both or load both without the "async defer".

Comment: I cant see the map even after removing async defer

Comment: You have to remove the `&callback=`, and add an onload function to run the `initMap` function.